# execute multiple update command on Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel, c#-4.0, ole

I have an Excel file and I want update multiple rows in a sheet.So I write this code :

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " + serverPath + ";Extended Properties = Excel 8.0;");
        try
        {

            strUpd = "";
            strUpd += "update [Data14City$] set  B_1_1 = 5 ,B_1_2 = 26 ,B_1_3 = 44 ,B_1_4 = 8  where id = 1 ";
            strUpd += " update [Data14City$] set  B_1_1 = 0 ,B_1_2 = 8 ,B_1_3 = 17 ,B_1_4 = 0  where id = 2";
            cn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(strUpd, cn);
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

and I got this error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'id = 1  update [Data14City$] set  B_1_1 = 0 ,B_1_2 = 8 ,B_1_3 = 17 ,B_1_4 = 0  where id = 2'.

and I when I add `;` to this line :

```
strUpd += "update [Data14City$] set  B_1_1 = 5 ,B_1_2 = 26 ,B_1_3 = 44 ,B_1_4 = 8  where id = 1;";
```

I got this error:

> Characters found after end of SQL statement.

how I can execute multiple statement in Excel?

thanks

Comment: Its missing either "AND"/"OR" :- "update [Data14City$] set  B_1_1 = 5 ,B_1_2 = 26 ,B_1_3 = 44 ,B_1_4 = 8  where id = 1 OR 
set B_1_1 = 0 ,B_1_2 = 8 ,B_1_3 = 17 ,B_1_4 = 0 where id = 2"

Comment: Ami right in saying your trying to achieve:-  UPDATE table SET A WHERE ID=1 OR/AND SET B WHERE ID=2? Have you tried the string above?

Comment: No.I have two update command for two rows

Comment: Your executing your command with one string value, which wont work because it will break at the end of the first statement. It has to be all one statement.

Comment: I don't think that Microsoft Jet OleDB 4.0 supports multiple update statements in the same OleDbCommand. [This article is rather old](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140022(v=office.10).aspx), but look at 'Multiple Results' property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to stack up your updates like that (in fact, as has been pointed out above, you can't). It doesn't take much longer to execute them individually. Here's the code I've been using and it works fine (I actually have mine in a loop, but it'll work equally well if you can't loop your updates).

```
cn.Open();

using (OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "update [Data14City$] set  B_1_1 = 5 ,B_1_2 = 26 ,B_1_3 = 44 ,B_1_4 = 8  where id = 1";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "update [Data14City$] set  B_1_1 = 0 ,B_1_2 = 8 ,B_1_3 = 17 ,B_1_4 = 0  where id = 2";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // ... and so on
}

cn.Close();
```