# Not able to update cell in excel woksheet using oledb connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I am trying to update execl sheet paricular sheet by writing this code:

```
    connExcel.Open();
    string SheetName = null;
    DataTable dtExcelSchema = null;
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    //checking sheet name
    if (dtExcelSchema.Rows[2]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("_xlnm#Database"))
    {
        SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[2]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    }

    if (!dtExcelSchema.Rows[2]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("_xlnm#Database"))
    {
        SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[2]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    }
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, SheetName, null });
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + SheetName + "] SET F11=22052", connExcel);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    connExcel.Close();
```

But this update query is updating the whole column while i just want update particular cell in excel say 'C9' accodring to excel sheet.

Any help will be appreciated.

My excel sheet looks like this..
[image: Excel template]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the syntax. You do it like this:

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ["+ SheetName +"$C9:C9] SET F11=22052", connExcel);
```

Comment: I am getting this error "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object ''Table I$'$C9:C9'". Also can u tell me how can i update row 9 in excel sheet

Comment: @abhishek This error generally occurred when you don't have `Table I$'$C9:C9` in excel file.

Comment: i want to update all cells in that row as shown in the image above.

Comment: @abhishek please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359748/execute-multiple-update-command-on-excel) for update multiple cells.

Comment: Can you please create the query as i m new to this! thanks